# Force react to render initial state with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I am trying to create a placeholder for area while data is loading. It is supposed to "grow" from the x axis.
I created simple function component as follows

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setVisible(true);
}, []);

return(
  <Area
    ....
    y0={d => visible ? d.y : 0}
  />
)
```

Problem probably is, that React is batching state updates - so sometimes the graph actually "grows" but sometimes it appears right away. Is there a way how to enforce rendering of the initial state? Or some other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios (working with a loader indicator) you should add some timeout for the animation (the "grow" effect):

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setVisible(true);
  }, 1000);
}, []);

return <Area y0={({ y }) => (visible ? y : 0)} />;
```